# Counting number of columns a value appears in (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google Sheet where I want to know the number of unique columns that a value appears in. For example, given the following sheet:

```
    |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+
    | Joe   | Lisa  | Lisa  | Lisa  |
    | Joe   | Lisa  | Jenny | Lisa  |
    | Joe   | Jenny | Jenny | John  |
    | Joe   | Jenny | Katie | John  |       
    | Joe   | Jenny | Katie | John  |
```

I would want something that counts Joe appearing in 1 column, Lisa appearing in 3, Jenny appearing in 2, Katie appearing in 1, and John appearing in one, i.e.

```
    | Name  | Count |
    +-------+-------+
    | Joe   |     1 |
    | Lisa  |     3 |
    | Jenny |     2 |
    | Katie |     1 |
    | John  |     1 |
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data has no spaces in it, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", QUERY(A1:D&"_"&COLUMN(A1:D1),,ROWS(A1:A)))," "))), "_"), "Select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 > 0 group by Col1 label count(Col2)''"))
```

If the source data has spaces, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SPLIT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(A1:D, " ", "~")&"_"&COLUMN(A1:D1),,ROWS(A1:A)))," "))), "_"), "Select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 > 0 group by Col1 label count(Col2)''"), "~", " "))
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

As Tom has noticed, I've missed the task, and the correct formula is:

```
=QUERY( 
    QUERY( 
    {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",1,FILTER(COLUMN(A:D)*row(A:D)^0,A:A<>"")),"#")), 
     TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",1,A:D),"#"))}, 
    "select Col1, Col2, count(Col2) group by Col1, Col2"), 
"select Col2, count(Col3) group by Col2 label Col2 'Name',count(Col3) 'Count'")
```

Credit: **@tom-sharpe**

My original formula counted max times name is in a row:

```
=QUERY(  
  QUERY(  
  {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",1,FILTER(COLUMN(A:D)^0*row(A:D),A:A<>"")),"#")),
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",1,A:D),"#"))},
  "select Col1, Col2, count(Col2) group by Col1, Col2"),
"select Col2, max(Col3) group by Col2 label Col2 'Name'")
```

[image]

Comment: I was interested to see how you put this together @Max but it only seems to give 3 Lisa's (for example) if they're in the same row?

Comment: This is my suggestion =QUERY(  
  QUERY(  
  {TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",1,FILTER(COLUMN(A:D)*row(A:D)^0,A:A<>"")),"#")),
   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",1,A:D),"#"))},
  "select Col1, Col2, count(Col2) group by Col1, Col2"),
"select Col2, count(Col3) group by Col2 label Col2 'Name',count(Col3) 'Count'")

Comment: Hi Tom. Thank you for the suggestion. I've added a screenshot of my result. I cannot see what exactly is wrong here. Please see my edit. @tom-sharpe

Comment: Well if you remove the Lisa in B6, you only get a count of 3 for Lisa, although she appears in all four columns. I think it's giving the max no. of Lisa's (or any other name) in any row.

Comment: Thank you, Tom! Now I see the difference.